# Ansible "until" not able to match the string

Tags: ansible

I am trying to display the output of the command using "until",

```
 - name: Waiting for stack to Deploy...
   shell: '{{ creds }} heat event-list {{stack_name}}'
   register: waiting_for_stack
   until: waiting_for_stack.stdout.find("Stack CREATE completed successfully") or waiting_for_stack.stdout.find("CREATE_FAILED")!= -1
   retries: 10
   delay: 3
 - debug: var=waiting_for_stack.stdout_lines
```

I am looping the shell command to get the entire event list of stack. But looping does not work. It is exiting from the first iteration without matching the string provided in conditions. Event list out-out looks like this.

```
ok: [10.206.41.150] => {
    "waiting_for_stack.stdout_lines": [
        "+---------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+----------------------+",
        "| resource_name | id                                   | resource_status_reason | resource_status    | event_time           |",
        "+---------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+----------------------+",
        "| stack01       | 924498f6-6498-4560-947c-fec5149b9775 | Stack CREATE started   | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS | 2016-05-12T02:55:18Z |",
        "| MCM2          | 1e6fe65d-971b-49c6-9441-dd77edd47d29 | state changed          | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS | 2016-05-12T02:55:18Z |",
        "+---------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------+----------------------+"
    ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to execute this? I am using ansible version 1.7 .

Answer (score 4):

```
until: ("Stack CREATE completed successfully" in waiting_for_stack.stdout) or ("CREATE_FAILED" in  waiting_for_stack.stdout)
```

Did the job for me.